# Is GPG symmetric encryption only based on a passphrase?

Tags: encryption, pgp

Is the symmetric key derived for AES only dependent on the passphrase?

Is it possible to generate the encryption key such that it is based on my primary GPG private key and temporary passphrase? In this case, the attacker would have to know the passphrase as well as my GPG key to decrypt the text.

Comment: What GPG and PGP _call_ symmetric does not use a privatekey (which they call secret). If you use what they _call_ publickey encryption it uses your static private key and its password, but no 'temporary' password.

Comment: So, there is no straightforward way to get a symmetric key from a temporary passphrase and my static private key?

Answer (score -1):

In GPG the symmetric key used to encrypt data is generated randomly.  That key is then wrapped (encrypted) using a public key or multiple public keys and anyone with any of those private keys can then unwrap (decrypt) the symmetric key and decrypt the data.  Typically, private keys are protected with passwords.  So yes, under normal circumstances, an attacker would need a copy of your encrypted private key and knowledge of your password in order to decrypt data sent to you.

Notice I said "multiple public keys" above.  So, anyone who's public key was included can decrypt the data so if multiple people are included in then any of them can decrypt the data and the compromise of any of their private keys or passwords would result in that encrypt data being compromised as well.

Comment: The classic and default encryption in PGP and GPG is as you describe hybrid: nonce DEK wrapped by RSA, ElG, or ECDH. But what PGP and GPG _call_ symmetric is wrapping the DEK by password-based encryption (only) using a derivation they call s2k (String To Key). See https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html#Operational-GPG-Commands and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-5.3 .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, yes my question is asking whether the String part (String to key) function only dependent on the passphrase I entered.  Your comment in the question answers it, I will mark it as accepted if you post it as an answer.